# USB LTE modem "Brovi E3372-325" not working Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: modem, lte, huawei

This is a continuation of the issue stated in [USB LTE modem "Brovi E3372-325" not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/733971/usb-lte-modem-brovi-e3372-325-not-working#new-answer?newreg=a5c7b27fe3154bc781cb3b7f4f1c3560)

I have a similar issue as [LaurentF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/734360/559692).

When I try to use the following udev rule

```
# This is part of USB_ModeSwitch version 1.x.x
#
ACTION!="add", GOTO="modeswitch_rules_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="usb", GOTO="modeswitch_rules_end"

# All known install partitions are on interface 0
ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}!="00", GOTO="modeswitch_rules_end"

# only storage class devices are handled; negative
# filtering here would exclude some quirky devices
ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="e0", GOTO="modeswitch_rules_begin"
ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="e0", GOTO="modeswitch_rules_begin"
GOTO="modeswitch_rules_end"

LABEL="modeswitch_rules_begin"
# Huawei E3372-325
ATTRS{idVendor}=="3566", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2001", RUN+="/sbin/usb_modeswitch -v 3566 -p 2001 -W -R -w 400"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="3566", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2001", RUN+="/sbin/usb_modeswitch -v 3566 -p 2001 -W -R"

LABEL="modeswitch_rules_end"
```

I find that my device never has a `bDeviceClass == "e0"` or a `bInterfaceClass == "e0"` and thus the usb_modeswitch is never run.

When I run them manually, it failes, in the same way as for LaurentF.

Anyone an idea how I should try to debug this?